# Bcrypt python script and JavaScript with MongoDB/Mongoose not working for two seperate items

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

Ok, I have a python script that does this to create a special account:

```
salt = bcrypt.gensalt(10)
password = (bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode("utf-8"), salt)).decode("utf-8")
pin = (bcrypt.hashpw(pin.encode("utf-8"), salt)).decode("utf-8")
```

I then store it in Mongodb as follows:

```
data = {
        'username' : username,
        'password' : password,
        'pin'      : pin,
        'created'  : t,
        'last_log' : t,
        'num_fails': 0,
        'systemWidePassword' : '[REDACTED]'
}
result = admins.insert_one(data)
```

If I check mongo, everything is in there.

I have a Mongoose method that checks the pin and password using bcrypt with the following line of code:

```
const [pinMatch, passMatch] = await Promise.all([
    bcrypt.compare(attemptPin, this.pin), 
    bcrypt.compare(attemptPass, this.password)
]);
```

For some reason, my `passMatch` evaluates to true everytime (with the correct password), **however my `pinMatch` value is always false with the correct pin.** Why would one work but the other always fail? All fields are handled as strings.

Comment: What is `bcrypt`? And `password` and `pin` aren't strings are they?

Comment: My schema stores them as strings. The encoding works for password and bcrypt is a library that is used for password hashing and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very unexpected. Apparently there is an issue with bcrypt and the '$' symbol. This lead to a situation where a generated password that had a '$' symbol causes a hash mismatch. I added the following to the python script after receiving the input for anything that will run through bcrypt:

```
def checkBcryptString(self, item):
    return item.find('$')
```

Then if it returns `True` I accept and with `False` it recursively asks for the item.